# SQL Server database connection string issue to run application in different machines

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I have created a desktop app it is working fine in my PC with the connection string as follows:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-IAS4D;Initial Catalog= MConsole;Integrated Security=True");
```

But it is not working on another PC. So I changed the connection string so that the application can be used in any PC:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MConsole.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;");
```

But I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Hp\source\repos\ MConsole\bin\Debug\Databases\MConsole.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I want my application to work in different machines with my database. Please resolve my issue. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to specify the path or the server, not both.

Comment: Also, if it's SQL Express, it's unlikely to be listening on anything other than localhost:1433 unless you've configured it differently through SQL Configuration Manager. You won't be able to connect to it across a network until you fix that.

Comment: The database is attached to a server (it is an mdf file).  You do not have access to the file and do not need th AttachDbFilename to the connection string.  Specifying the server name and  instance (SQLExpress) of the server on the remote machine is all that you need in the connection string.  So all you need is to replace the period in the connection string with the server name as well as removing the AttachDbFilename.

Comment: Please avoid these [`AttachDbFilename` shenanigans](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename). This feature is intended for local development only, and it's terrible even at that. Next, you need to figure out if you want to connect to the default instance of SQL Server, or a named instance called `SQLEXPRESS`. I feel like if you installed SQL Express with default settings on one machine, and want to connect to it from another, you'll want `machinename\SQLEXPRESS` - but the ill-advised dash in the machine name might introduce a wrinkle.